# Android - Best Location Tracking Strategy

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am trying to write a location tracking service that starts as soon as the app is started, stops as soon as the app goes into the background, and restarts as soon as the app comes back to the foreground.

The service should poll for a new location every 5 minutes while it is running (to conserve battery) and when a new location is found (onLocationChanged()) it updates a variable that I can retrieve from any Activity.

I have tried binding a service in my custom Application class but the service never is bound before my initial Activity loads - and my initial Activity requires this service so I keep getting a null pointer exception when trying to access the service.

But maybe I am going in the wrong direction - what would be the best strategy for this? I don't need a super exact location and I don't care if it comes from the GPS or Network.

Comment: Do you need a location in onCreate?

Comment: I was able to change my code so that it would wait to do certain things until the service was officially bound but now I can't come up with a good way of stopping this service when the user leaves the app